# Problema al intentar ejecutar una consulta SQL desde pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, firebird

tengo la siguiente función, la cual, toma unos cuits desde una grilla y los inserta en una tabla temporal. Estoy usando delphi XE7 y Firebird 2.5.

```
function TfImportacionArchivoARBARetenPercep.fxListarClientesProveedoresNoEnGrilla(
  pboClientes: Boolean): WideString;
var
  wsAux : WideString;
  stTabla, stCuit: String;
  qCliProv,qCuitsExcluidos,qCuit : TFXQuery;
  niFila : Integer;

begin
  wsAux := '';
  qCuitsExcluidos := fDatos.fxCrearQuery; 
  qCuit := fDatos.fxCrearQuery;

  qCuitsExcluidos.SQL.Text := 'Create global temporary table TempExcluidos (cuitExcluido varchar(13)) on commit delete rows';
  qCuitsExcluidos.ExecSQL;

  if pboClientes then
  begin
    stTabla := 'Clientes'
  end
  else
  begin
    stTabla := 'Proveedores';

  end;
  for niFila := 1 to gDetalle.RowCount - 1 do
    if Trim(gDetalle.Cells[3,niFila]) <> '' then
    Begin
      stCuit := QuotedStr(Trim(gDetalle.Cells[3,niFila]));
      qCuit.SQL.Text := 'Insert into TempExcluidos(:cuitExcluido)';
      qCuit.ParamByName('cuitExcluido').AsString := stCuit;
      qCuit.ExecSQL;//←←←←Esta es la linea que lanza la excepcion
    End;

  qCuitsExcluidos.SQL.Text :='';
  qCuitsExcluidos.SQL.Text := 'commit;';
  qCuitsExcluidos.SQL.Add('drop table TempExcluidos;');
  qCuitsExcluidos.SQL.Add('commit;');
  qCuitsExcluidos.ExecSQL;

  qCliProv := fDatos.fxCrearQuery;

  try
    qCliProv.SQL.Text :=
      ' Select Codigo' +
      '   From ' + stTabla +
      '  Where Activo = 1 ';

    if gDetalle.RowCount  > 0 then
      begin
        qCliProv.SQL.Add('And Cuit Not In (Select cuitExcluido from TempExcluidos)');
      end;

    qCliProv.Open;

    wsAux := '';

    while not qCliProv.Eof do
    begin
      wsAux := wsAux + iif((wsAux = ''), '', ',') + qCliProv.FieldByName('Codigo').AsString;
      qCliProv.Next;
    end;

    Result := wsAux;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qCliProv);
    FreeAndNil(qCuit);
    FreeAndNil(qCuitsExcluidos);
  end;
end;
```

La función `fDatos.fxCrearQuery` arma la consulta para luego agregarle el texto y ejecutar. Desconozco la implementación del mismo, pero otras consultas funcionan bien.
Cuando se intenta ejecutar la linea `qCuit.ExecSQL;` salta la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento ejecutar un select sobre esa tabla me sale el error `SQL error code = -204 Table unknown`. Este error no debería salir, ya que creo una tabla temporal en una linea anterior.

Comment: En Firebird, las tabla temporales son parte del esquema. Lo menciono porque no creo que debas crearla como parte de este proceso, sino que la tabla ya debiera estar creada (junto al resto de tablas de tu sistema). Indica si tu error persiste al ejecutar el código ya existiendo la tabla.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me decis. El problema es que necesito crear esta tabla y que despues se borre, ya que, solo la necesito en este proceso. El problema es el sistema en general, esta muy mal diseñado. Entonces por ahi tengo consultas con mas de 70000 caracteres y el motor explota. Por ejemplo en este caso tengo una consulta que tiene que hacer un NOT IN contra 7000 Cuit que son VARCHAR(13). La verdad no se me ocurre otra solucion

Comment: ¿Por qué tendrías que borrar esta tabla? En realidad, pasaría a formar parte del sistema, ¿no?

Comment: No no, en realidad es algo poco prolijo que necesito hacer. Esta tabla solo me va a servir para comparar contra una consulta que tiene un NOT IT. Es solo para esto, despues ya no tiene utilidad alguna, por eso estaba intentando con tablas temporales, para que una vez cerrada la conexion se borre

Comment: comprendo, si es algo que se va a ejecutar una única vez en la vida, está bien... aún así, podrías crear la tabla manualmente, ejecutar el proceso y luego eliminarla. Lo digo porque sospecho que el cliente de firedac tiene algún problema recuperando la metadata de esa tabla, por eso no logra interpretar el parámetro (es una sospecha, no estoy seguro, el error no me parece lógico).

Comment: Veo varios problemas con tu código, pero ninguno de esos resolvería el mensaje de error que estás teniendo.